# Second Service.AllAsync() returns empty ICollection, when mocking DbSet and ApplicationDbContext on EF6

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to test the method `DepartmentSerive.SearchAsync(string name)` using `Moq`. So far, I've followed this [msdn tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429) about how to mock `DbSet` and `ApplicationDbContext`  classes.

First, I copied `DbAsyncQueryProvider` implementation, so I could use the asynchronous methods.

Then I implemented my `DepartmentService : Service<TEntity>` class.

```
public class DepartmentService : Service<Department>
{
    public DepartmentService(ApplicationDbContext db) : base(db) { }

    public async Task<ICollection<Department>> SearchAsync(string name)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            return await AllAsync();
        }

        return await db.Departments
            .Where(d => d.Name.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()))
            .OrderBy(d => d.Name)
            .ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

`Service<TEntity>` is a generic service with methods like `AllSync`, `Insert`, `Update`, `Delete`, but the relevant part is here:

```
public abstract class Service<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public virtual async Task<ICollection<TEntity>> AllAsync()
    {
        return await db.Set<TEntity>().ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

I have a `Setup` method as this:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Setup()
{
    var data = new List<Department>
    {
        new Department { Id = 1, Name = "Computer Science" },
        new Department { Id = 2, Name = "Political Science" },
        new Department { Id = 3, Name = "Physics" },
        new Department { Id = 4, Name = "Mathematics" },
    }.AsQueryable();

    var set = new Mock<DbSet<Department>>();
    set.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<Department>>().Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator()).Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<Department>(data.GetEnumerator()));
    set.As<IQueryable<Department>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<Department>(data.Provider));
    set.As<IQueryable<Department>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        set.As<IQueryable<Department>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
    set.As<IQueryable<Department>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

    context = new Mock<ApplicationDbContext>();
    context.Setup(c => c.Set<Department>()).Returns(set.Object);
    context.Setup(c => c.Departments).Returns(set.Object);
}
```

And finally my test:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task SearchWithEmptyString()
{
    var service = new DepartmentService(context.Object);
    var result = await service.SearchAsync(null);
    Assert.AreEqual(4, result.Count);

    result = await service.SearchAsync("");
    Assert.AreEqual(4, result.Count);
}
```

My test should pass, considering `null` and `""` will be handled in the same way by `SearchAsync()`, but it's actually failing on the second `Assert.AreEqual(4, result.Count);`. For some reason, the first call to `AllAsync()` in the service returns the entire list, but the second one returns an empty one, as if `AllAsync()` were returning the elements, but also emptying the list in the process.
This problem doesn't happen when I'm using the real database. I wrote two sequential `AllAsync()` at `DepartmentController` and the second one still returns the correct data.

Am I doing something wrong, when mocking the list, or setting up the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. Turns out that after interacting with the `IEnumerator<T> _inner` contained in Microsoft's implementation for `internal class TestDbAsyncEnumerator<T>`, the property `Current` wasn't being reset, staying in the last position and, therefore, being evaluated as `null` in the second call for `await db.Set<TEntity>().ToListAsync();`.

So, just adding `_inner.Reset();` in the method `Dispose()` of the class `TestDbAsyncEnumerator<T>` solves the problem! You have to put it inside a try-catch block, considering `AsyncQueryProvider` does not implement the `Reset()` method and the method `Dispose()` is also called after making a query.

```
internal class TestDbAsyncEnumerator<T> : IDbAsyncEnumerator<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerator<T> _inner;

    public TestDbAsyncEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> inner)
    {
        _inner = inner;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            _inner.Reset();
        }
        catch (NotSupportedException)
        {
            //
        }
        _inner.Dispose();
    }

    public Task<bool> MoveNextAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(_inner.MoveNext());
    }

    public T Current
    {
        get { return _inner.Current; }
    }

    object IDbAsyncEnumerator.Current
    {
        get { return Current; }
    }
}
```